# How to convert Joda time LocalTime to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to convert Joda LocalTime to java.util.Date and **not** LocalDate. If this helps, I already have a LocalTime object with me. Obviously, there is no "date" part in LocalTime. So I cannot convert LocalTime to Date directly. Is there a simple way to do this ?

Steps -

```
LocalTime loct 
LocalDate locd = Todays date + loct
Date da = locd.toDate();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Date da = loct.toDateTimeToday().toDate();
```

Comment: And don't forget to decide which timezone you want to use, otherwise you could have a lot of fun ocasionally during DST dates. This expression uses JVM default tz.

Comment: @kan or specific TZ, setted by `DateTimeZone#setDefault(DateTimeZone)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
locd.withFields(loct).toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this--

```
Date dtUtil = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toDate();
```

the generic way is -

```
Date dtUtil = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("TimeZoneString")).toDate();
```

where "TimeZoneString"is timeZone id for which you want to get the time.

DateTimeZone.getDefault() will return the local zone of the system.